# File explorer does not automatically refresh changes when connected to WSL file system

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-11, wsl2

On Windows 11 with WSL 2 installed, if I open the WSL file system in Windows File Explorer by using the provided `\\wsl.localhost` UNC path, I am able to browse all my files on the WSL file system.

However, if any change is made on the WSL side (addition, removal of files and folders), those changes are not reflected immediately in File Explorer. Instead, I have to refresh the view to get the changes to appear.

This has some significant downstream effects for me. Is anyone aware of why this happens or if there is a way to change the behavior so that Windows detects file system changes when browsing the WSL file system via the provided network path?

Answer (score 1):

This same question was raised in the bug-report
[Need to manually refresh file explorer in WSL to see changes, both windows10 and windows11 #7941](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7941).

The only answer was :

> This is the expected behaviour, wsl folder is not native windows folder and being used by linux.

In other words, WSL does not inform Windows utilities such
as Explorer of file changes.

You will need to keep on refreshing the display to see changes.
This might change in the future, as WSL is under constant development. For the moment, all you can do is file another
bug report via the Feedback Hub.